# How can I integrate Intercom in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to add Intercom in a Xamarin.Forms application for iOS but things aren't going well.

Existing nuget packages aren't compatible with the current version of Xamarin and Intercom doesn't offer support for Xamarin integration, there are only third party libraries, but they are out-of-date.

Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: I would suggest you check this thread https://community.intercom.com/t/intercom-xamarin-sdks/761/2

Comment: Thanks for the quick-answer @G.hakim, of course, this is the first thing I did, but from the three available options, no one is compatible with the current version of Xamarin.

Comment: Well, then you have your answer I suppose!